# How to decrease the size of lightning page

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I have created a LWC page but everything on the page is zoomed in, it looks good when I decrease the percentage to 80%, can anyone suggest if is it possible to decrease the size of everything on lwc including buttons, input fields and text size or we can load the page on 80 % zoom level instead of default 100 %

Page at default 100 % zoom level
[image]

Page at default 80% zoom level

[image]

Comment: Where are you loading it? which parts of page are zoomed? can you show screenshot?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) function in CSS. Example for outermost component CSS:

```
* {
    transform: scale(0.8); // 80% zoom/scale
}
```

Output:

[image]

And here is the [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/tcaxQ-jiX/1/edit) for you.

Comment: Thank you for responding but the above Css is not working

Comment: Depends on which component you are adding CSS. Did you check playground?

Comment: Yes I checked the Playground, this css adds a border on all side of the page. 80% should be displayed on the complete window  and in my case it also addes the border I need to scroll right to see the content of my page.